# What is the difference between 种类，类型 and 品种?

Tags: difference

See title. What's the difference between these terms? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're better off giving your context, or it's hard to give an good answer for it.

Comment: See https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/30155/3613 about subtle differences in meaning in general.

Answer (score 2):

They can all be translated into English as *variety* or *type*. Their differences are:

- **種類**

  - Has a slight emphasis on the *differences* between compared things, and it is slightly more often used to construct categories to sort different objects into.
  - Also occasionally used as a synonym for **種族** (*race* or *ethnicity*) in older texts (pre-Qing).
  - Example from Pleco: 不同**種類**的刀具 (*different kinds of knives*)
- **類型**

  - Has a slight emphasis on the *similarities* between compared things, and it is slightly more often used to group things which share similar properties into the same category.
  - Sometimes used as a word to categorise *tropes*, *imagery*, or *genres* in the field of literature.
  - Is a term imported from [Wasei-kango](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasei-kango).
  - Example sentence: 魯迅 《偽自由書ㆍ前記》： “然而我的壞處， 是在論時事不留面子， 砭錮弊常取**類型**， 而後者尤與時宜不合。” (*Lu Xun: "My problem is that I don't spare any sensibilities when discussing current affairs, and often use **literary tropes** when criticising harmful traditions; the latter may be extremely inappropriate in contemporary society."*)
- **品種**

  - Very often used in the field of biology for the meaning *animal **breed***, ***species***, *bacterial **strain***.
  - Otherwise used to describe the assortment variety of products e.g. in a shop.